# Removing items from JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I've got a simple Jlist with data from `List<String>`, Now I want to remove selected item from Jlist.
Here is the code:

```
final DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel();
final JList list = new JList(model);

//filling list
//loop for every element from List<String>
 public static void sample(DefaultListModel model, List<String> data)
      for(int i=;i<data.size();i++)
        {model.addElement(data.get(i));}

//btn pressed
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
    model.removeElementAt(index);
}
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.removeIndexInterval(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.intervalRemoved(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireIntervalRemoved(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListModel.remove(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is the any trick or something?
Thanks for help.

Comment: getSelectedIndex() returns -1 if nothing selected, and only indexes 0 or more are valid...

Comment: I check the value of the index and it is correct!

Comment: The stacktrace doesn't look at all related to your the code you posted.

Comment: When i want to clear or remove any element from the list I get this stacktrace.

Comment: More code is needed, preferrably an SSCCE.  What is model defined as?

Comment: I added the inicalization of model

Comment: How are you setting the data on the JList? You haven't shown that in your code snippet.  I suspect that you populate the JList elsewhere which may be causing a new underlying model to be created, thus making your variable "model" useless.

Comment: +1 with @splungebob - how/where do you add elements to your model?

Comment: updated. I'm adding elements in the function.

Comment: The code you posted is irrelevant. The stacktrace suggests that you are modifying an `ArrayList` which has nothing to do with the `JList` or the `DefaultListModel` you use in the `JList` (as that uses a `Vector` internally). Post more of the stack-trace, and the part of your code that appears in the stack trace

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your index is non-negative (as mentioned by others), see if this works (in your listener):

```
((DefaultListModel) jList.getModel()).remove(index);
```

If so, then you're using using a stale model.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#removeElementAt%28int%29), using `remove()` instead of `removeElementAt()` is recommended, so :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
    if (index != -1) {
        model.remove(index);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the Javadoc for [`getSelectedIndex()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedIndex%28%29):

> Returns the smallest selected cell index; the selection when only a
>   single item is selected in the list. When multiple items are selected,
>   it is simply the smallest selected index. **Returns -1 if there is no
>   selection**

The reason that you're experiencing the error is because for some reason, no items are selected from your list and as such -1 is returned by this method. When you call `removeElementAt()` and pass it -1 as a parameter value, it would throw you the exception.

What you need to do is as follows:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
    if(index >= 0){ //Remove only if a particular item is selected
        model.removeElementAt(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: @extra90: I don't think this is where the exception occurs. Please: 1. Post the full stack trace and 2. Post your full code or an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) version of your code

Answer (score 1):

The question is that you have a problem in the listener, because when the element is removed the selected value will change. This is the reason that your "valueChanged" method is trying to get the selectedValue in a wrong position.
I can't see your method valueChanged, but I think this is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
DefaultListModel model=new DefaultListModel();
    model.clear();
 jList1.setModel(model);
```

if you want delete all item

Answer (score 0):

```
int selectedIndex = yourJLIST.getSelectedIndex();
    String [] ListData = new String[yourJLIST.getModel().getSize()];
    for (int i = 0; i < ListData.length; i++) {
        if(i == selectedIndex){
            
        }else{
            ListData[i] = yourJLIST.getModel().getElementAt(i);
        }
    }
    yourJLIST.setListData(ListData);
```