# deleing element from one of dual jlist

Tags: java, swing

want to delete item/s from 2nd list , any way to do without ListModel ..?

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings({ "serial", "rawtypes", "deprecation", "unchecked" })
public class Class_GUI_Test_1 extends JFrame {

    JList list1, list2;
    JButton add, remove, add_all;

    private String[] names = { "hTC Explorer", "S_G_Nexus_s", "hTC Amaze", "LG OPTIMUS G" };

    public Class_GUI_Test_1() {
        super("TEST");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // BoxLayout(getContentPane(),
                                     // BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        list1 = new JList(names);
        list1.setVisibleRowCount(3);
        list1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        add(new JScrollPane(list1));

        add = new JButton("Add");
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                list2.setListData(list1.getSelectedValues());
            }
        });

        add(add);

        list2 = new JList();
        list2.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        list2.setFixedCellHeight(25);
        list2.setVisibleRowCount(3);
        list2.setFixedCellWidth(150);
        add(new JScrollPane(list2));

        add_all = new JButton("ADD All DATA");
        add_all.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                list2.setListData(names);

            }
        });

        add(add_all);

        remove = new JButton("Remove_Data");
        remove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                list2.add(list1); // this is where i need help.
                int index = list2.getSelectedIndex();
                if (index >= 0)
                    list2.remove(index);

            }
        });

        add(remove);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class_GUI_Test_1 gui = new Class_GUI_Test_1();
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setSize(250, 350);
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Creating, Adding and Deleting Elements from a JList

`JList`s may be initialized with a set of strings using the constructor

```
public JList(Object[] listData)
```

for example, you can supply an array of Strings:

```
String[] ar = {"one", "two", "three"};
JList list = new JList(ar);
```

However, [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) has no method to add or delete items once it is initialized.  Instead, if you need to do this, you must use the [ListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) class with a JList.  Think of the ListModel as the object which holds the items in the JList.

1. Declare an instance of [DefaultListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html):

   ```
   DefaultListModel listModel;
   ```
2. Create it:

   ```
   listModel = new DefaultListModel();
   ```
3. Populate it (now or later):

   ```
   listModel.addElement(“item 1”);
   listModel.addElement(“item 2”);
   ```
4. Use the DefaultListModel in the constructor of a JList (instead of a String array):

   ```
   JList list = new JList(listModel);
   ```
5. Now to add additional elements at any time during execution, use addElement() again and it will show up in the JList. (You can also use add(int index) where you specify the 0-based position of the element to be added.)

   ```
   listModel.addElement(“new item”);
   ```
6. To delete an item, just call below method where n is the 0-based index of the item to remove.  It will disappear.

   ```
    listModel.remove(n);
   ```
7. To delete all the items, call

   ```
    listModel.clear();
   ```

---

Some points:

- [JList#getSelectedValues()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValues%28%29) is a *Deprecated* method so don't use it.
- Don't simply suppress the warnings.
- Even if don't specify the [ListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) it by default uses [AbstractListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html)

Comment: http://www.seasite.niu.edu/cs580java/JList_Basics.htm
btw i needed a confirmation of doing it w/o ListModel so u confirmed it so i have to use l.m. buddy my problem is that i'm using two lists one for all data other for selected / desired data. then after inserting into object of l.m i have to do this list1  = new JList(listmodel);

Comment: Look at the last point of my post. So use `ListModel` that provides convenient methods for these type of operations. Read more about [Removing items from JList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298711/removing-items-from-jlist)

Comment: thanks , but why there is a negative vote to the thread... ? :/

Comment: Don't know who down-voted it without any comment. May be your question is not clear. Just update your question again to describe the problem where you stuck in your program. Whenever you post your code you need to describe it in words as well.

Comment: Thanks, will try to elaborate my questions from now on. @Braj
Any contact link of you please...? (email/ fb)

Comment: remove  = new JButton("Remove_Data");
remove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
list2.add(list1);
int[] indices = list2.getSelectedIndices();
for(int i  = indices.length-1 ; i>=0 ;i--)
list2.remove(indices[i]);
}});
add(remove);